# Trying to recover Zpool

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, zfs, motherboard

I am having a terrible time with moving to a new motherboard. I upgraded to improve the a plex server running docker containers. I initially cloned the ssd to a new NVME. I am unable to find the zpool on this. None of the four hard drives show up in boot or ubuntu. I was unable to access the internet and ended up having to clean install thinking updated firmware could help... No, the zpool does not import or is found. I cannot see any of the HDD, but I can see the SSDs x2 with cables. Motherboard is b360m D2v. I have updated bios.

I am at my wits end about this, I am not proficient in any means, but usually I can figure my way out of these things. I don't know if the HDD got damaged, but they were just sitting there. I had a zpool as /mnt/media/medialibrary/movies.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a whole lot more detail for anyone (including me) to help. Please include output of `lsblk` in your question as a start - if the system can't even see the disks as block devices, then this is the first problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: I also assume (but you didn't tell) that the four disks will be identified in Ubuntu as `sda` to `sdd`. In this case, try output of this command, to see kernel boot messages related to disks: `dmesg | grep "sd[abcd]"`